# Random numbers without repeat

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, numbers, repeat

```
random rd = new random();
int name = rd.Next(0,9);
```

`if(name == 1 )` something will happen
`if(name == 2 )` something will happen
`if(name == 3 )` something will happen
`if(name == 4 )` something will happen
`if(name == 5 )` something will happen
.
.
.

How do I make it so it doesn't repeat?

Comment: Use a switch statement, or use a lookup/dictionary to map `int` to `Action`

Comment: If you don't want repeating numbers, don't use a Random - create a list of the numbers, and sort it in a random order, then iterate through that.

Comment: @stuartd I think the OP means: without repeating (too much) code

Comment: @PeterB I think you may be right. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: your title and description are completely diff....if you are looking to optimize redundant code then answer by Rob is best.... otherwise as stated by Stuartd, do not use Random and use list of numbers instead

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want to call all the actions in random order; to do that, *create* actions, say, an array:

```
  Action[] actions = new Action[] {
    () => {Console.Write("I'm the first");},
    () => {Console.Write("I'm the second");},
    ...
    () => {Console.Write("I'm the tenth");},
  };
```

then *shuffle* the collection (array):

```
  // simpelst, not thread safe
  static Random generator = new Random();

  ...

  int low = actions.GetLowerBound(0);
  int high = actions.GetUpperBound(0);

  for (int i = low; i < high; ++i) {
    int index = i + generator.Next(high - i + 1);

    var h = actions.GetValue(i);
    actions.SetValue(actions.GetValue(index), i);
    actions.SetValue(h, index);
  }
```

finally, *call*:

```
  foreach (var action in actions)
    action();
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in some comments, you should create a list (or a stack/queue, depending on your exact implementation) that is sorted "randomly". So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> allElements = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            allElements.Add(i);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        Queue<int> myQueue = new Queue<int>(allElements.OrderBy(e => rnd.NextDouble()));

        while (myQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            int currentInt = myQueue.Dequeue();
            Console.WriteLine(currentInt);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, and just a comment: The thing I wrote works, but I'm not convinced of an actual case where you would want to do that.